# Unable to write jest test case for file upload onChange event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm new in writing test case, trying to write for onChange event while uploading File in react. I've gone through some of the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557325/react-testing-library-typescript-upload-file) but still couldn't find any answer to it.

Here is the code:

```
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div
        className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? "dragging" : ""}`}
        onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
        onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDrop={handleDrop}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          id="input-file-upload"
          className="inputFile"
          data-testid="input-field"
          onChange={handleFileInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="input-file-upload" id="label-file-upload">
          <div>
            <button
              style={{ display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
              onClick={handleButtonClick}
            >
              Add File
            </button>
            {selectedFile ? (
              <p>Selected File: {selectedFile.name}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>Drag and drop files</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

OnChange event:

```
const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    console.log(file);
  };
```

Test case:

```
test.only("input field onChange", () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId("input-field")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Unable to cover onChange event, not sure how to do it (here, input element field is not visible). Here is the link for full code (https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-glade-x9h48c?file=/src/tests/index.test.tsx:117-246).
Could anyone please help me in this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`upload()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#upload) API of `user-event` to upload files and trigger the `onChange` event handler of `<input type='file' />` React built-in component.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App() {
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(true);
    };

    const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(false);
    };

    const handleDragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(false);

        const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
        setSelectedFile(file);
        console.log(file);
    };

    const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setSelectedFile(file);
    };

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        document.getElementById('input-file-upload').click();
    };

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div
                className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? 'dragging' : ''}`}
                onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
                onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
                onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                onDrop={handleDrop}
            >
                <input
                    type='file'
                    id='input-file-upload'
                    className='inputFile'
                    data-testid='input-field'
                    onChange={handleFileInputChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor='input-file-upload' id='label-file-upload'>
                    <div>
                        <button style={{ display: 'block', margin: 'auto' }} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                            Add File
                        </button>
                        {selectedFile ? <p>Selected File: {selectedFile.name}</p> : <p>Drag and drop files</p>}
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from './index';

test.only('input field onChange', async () => {
    render(<App />);
    const input = screen.getByTestId('input-field');
    expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
    const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' });

    await userEvent.upload(input, file);
    expect(screen.getByText('Selected File: hello.png')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/76759159/index.test.jsx (9.761 s)
  ✓ input field onChange (84 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-----------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s     
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-----------------------
All files  |   54.17 |       75 |   28.57 |   54.17 |                       
 index.jsx |   54.17 |       75 |   28.57 |   54.17 | 8-9,13-14,18,22-27,36 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-----------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.089 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: Thank yo so much for helping me :). You saved my day!. Could you help in drag and drop file one too.

Comment: @Sandhya Then you should ask a new question with a minimal, reproducible example, one post should contain one question.

Comment: Sure, will raise a question. Thank you so much!